# RecyclerView adapter - onCreateViewHolder receives unknown viewType

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I got a weird exception in the function onCreateViewHolder inside my custom adapter. Probably because getItemViewType function returns different values as expected.

This is how getItemViewType function looks like:

```
private static final int TYPE_HEADER = 0;
private static final int TYPE_ITEM = 1;

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
  if (position == 0)
    return TYPE_HEADER;

  return TYPE_ITEM;
}
```

As you can see, it returns 0 or 1 only, no other option.

This is how onCreateViewHolder function looks like:

```
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
  if (viewType == TYPE_HEADER) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.my_groups, null);
    return new HeaderHolder(view);
  } else if(viewType == TYPE_ITEM) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.explore_group_row, null);
    return new ItemHolder(view);
  }

  throw new RuntimeException("there is no type that matches the type " + viewType + " make sure your using types correctly");
}
```

However, I got some crashes from crashlytics that there is no type that matches with viewTypes of 6, 7, 8, 11, etc.. Not sure where it gets from...
In addition, I can't reproduce this issue, no idea how it happens.

I saw a similar issue in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51220412/recyclerview-adapter-getitemviewtype-method-sometimes-returns-2-8-etc-etc-inst) but no solution.

Here you can see the exception from crashlytics:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: there is no type that matches the type 6 make sure your using types correctly
       at com.example.eliran.forum.GroupsFragment$GroupsAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(GroupsFragment.java:72)
       at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5)
       at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.a(RecyclerView.java:295)
       at androidx.recyclerview.widget.GapWorker.prefetchPositionWithDeadline(GapWorker.java:14)
       at androidx.recyclerview.widget.GapWorker.flushTaskWithDeadline(GapWorker.java:15)
       at androidx.recyclerview.widget.GapWorker.flushTasksWithDeadline(GapWorker.java:22)
       at androidx.recyclerview.widget.GapWorker.a(GapWorker.java:3)
       at androidx.recyclerview.widget.GapWorker.run(GapWorker.java:71)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7078)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:965)
```

Here's the full code of the adapter:

```
private class GroupsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

        private static final int TYPE_HEADER = 0;
        private static final int TYPE_ITEM = 1;

        @Override
        public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            if (viewType == TYPE_HEADER) {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.my_groups, null);
                return new HeaderHolder(view);
            } else if(viewType == TYPE_ITEM) {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.explore_group_row, null);
                return new ItemHolder(view);
            }

            throw new RuntimeException("there is no type that matches the type " + viewType + " make sure your using types correctly");
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int i) {
            if (holder instanceof ItemHolder) {
                ItemHolder theHolder = (ItemHolder) holder;
                Group group = groups.get(i - 1);
                theHolder.title.setText(group.getTitle());
                theHolder.description.setText(group.getDescription());

                if(group.getImage() != null) {
                    Picasso.get()
                            .load(group.getImage())
                            .fit()
                            .into(theHolder.image);
                } else {
                    Picasso.get()
                            .load(R.drawable.profile_picture_holder)
                            .fit()
                            .into(theHolder.image);
                }
            } else if (holder instanceof HeaderHolder){
                HeaderHolder theHolder = (HeaderHolder) holder;
                if (showMyGroupsPb) {
                    theHolder.myGroupsPb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    theHolder.myGroupSectionHeader.setOnBtnListener(null);
                } else {
                    theHolder.myGroupsPb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    theHolder.myGroupSectionHeader.setOnBtnListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(rootView.getContext(), MyGroupsActivity.class);
                            intent.putExtra("groups", myGroups);
                            startActivityForResult(intent, TheFinals.JOIN_LEAVE_GROUP_CODE);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position) {
            if (position == 0)
                return TYPE_HEADER;

            return TYPE_ITEM;
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return groups.size() + 1;
        }

        class HeaderHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

            private ProgressBar myGroupsPb;
            private SectionHeader myGroupSectionHeader;

            public HeaderHolder(View view) {
                super(view);

                myGroupsRv = view.findViewById(R.id.groupsRecyclerView);
                myGroupsPb = view.findViewById(R.id.pb);
                LinearLayoutManager horizontalLayoutManager
                        = new LinearLayoutManager(rootView.getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
                myGroupsRv.setLayoutManager(horizontalLayoutManager);
                myGroupsRv.setAdapter(myGroupAdapter);
                myGroupSectionHeader = view.findViewById(R.id.myGroupSectionHeader);
            }


        }

        class ItemHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
            protected TextView title;
            protected ImageView image;
            protected TextView description;

            public ItemHolder(View view) {
                super(view);
                this.title = view.findViewById(R.id.title);
                this.image = view.findViewById(R.id.image);
                this.description = view.findViewById(R.id.description);
                view.setOnClickListener(this);
            }

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                int itemPosition = groupsRecyclerView.getChildLayoutPosition(view) - 1;
                selectedGroupIndex = itemPosition;
                Intent intent = new Intent(rootView.getContext(), GroupActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("group", groups.get(itemPosition));
                startActivityForResult(intent, TheFinals.JOIN_LEAVE_GROUP_CODE);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well that's pretty damn weird, perhaps a bug with RecyclerView? If you find no solution I suggest making a fallback "error" view type that's blank or says "error" so the app doesn't crash.

Comment: Yeah, pretty damn weird too from me. Never encountered it even once. I could only be thinking of two possibilities aside from the `RecyclerView.Adapter` bug. One would be the error might have been thrown by previous version(s) of your app, but you should have been aware of that in this case. Case number 2, your Firebase config (google-services.json) might have been stolen (since it is possible to get it from the APK) and being used without your consent. In all, I'm just commenting instead of answering because I'm really not sure beyond that :)